# Citations as footnotes in Markdown

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, pandoc, markdown

I use markdown for writing a document and have a bibliography in a seperate .bib file. Citations are used with `[@id]` in the document and when I use pandoc to convert my markdown file to PDF I get the citations on the last page.

While that generally works fine for me I need to have the citations both as footnotes as well as in form of a list on the last page of the document. I know that I could use footnotes with `^[text]` but I want to have the citations from my bibliography styled as defined in a csl file, not just some hardwritten text. And I need it at the end of the file as well as in footnotes.

What would the easiest way to achieve what I need to do be? I don't really have the time to learn and switch to LaTeX right now, is it even possible to do this with markdown and pandoc? If not, can I use inline LaTeX somehow to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `pandoc-citeproc` you simply have to choose a style, that supports footnotes.

1. Go to the [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles?format=note) and filter for `note`:

[image]

2. Download a style you like and install it in a place where `pandoc` can find it (like your working directory or `~/.local/share/pandoc/csl`). For this example, I chose `chicago-fullnote-bibliography-short-title-subsequent.csl`
3. Prepare a markdown file:

```
---
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: chicago-fullnote-bibliography-short-title-subsequent.csl 
---

Here I cite the paper.[@id]

# Bibliography
```

4. Call pandoc:

```
pandoc in.md --filter pandoc-citeproc -o out.pdf
```

5. Et voilà:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I already spent some time tweaking my csl to my needs and I would like to continue using it. I created it with [this editor](https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/). Do you happen to know how I need to modify the csl to be like the "note" styles on zotero?

Comment: One more question: Is there a way to have the same numbers that are used for the footnotes in front of the citations at the end of the document? I think it would look better and be more intuitive but I can't find a style doing that. I'm not really into academia though, maybe it is just bad practice for some reason.

Comment: You can change the option `class` from `in-text` to `note` in the visual editor under `STYLE INFO`→ `Global Formatting Options`

Comment: Well I guess this belongs to my original question: I said in the OP that I already have a custom citation style. Changing from `in-text` to `note` creates footnotes like `1 [1]` which isn't really that helpful.
But I guess I will open another question tomorrow to prevent a long comment chain